# How to start native activity while the current activity is still initiating

Tags: android, android-activity

I need an advice on how to start native activity while the current activity is still initiating.. I read the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and I don't see what would be the right way to get what I need.

So to explain...

I need to start the native video activity and play some video depending on some conditions.
So instead of the following:

```
1. User launch an app (main activity is started)
2. Welcome screen is displayed while the app is loading
3. App is ready & running
```

I need something like this:

```
1. User launch an app
1.1. Check If some video is available
1.2. Play the video 
1.3. Once the video is finished or user press the back key, continue to step 2.
2. Welcome screen is displayed while the app is loading
3. App is ready & running
```

My current attempt is based on the fact than an activity is paused as soon as some new activity is started so I'm simply starting my video activity in onResume call of the main activity:

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (someCondition && !videoIsPlayed)
    {
        videoIsPlayed = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        final Uri data = Uri.parse(videoURL);
        intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

However, I didn't found any evidence that above code is actually safe...

Other idea that I have is to introduce  two activities that would be something like an activity chooser where in onCreate I would chose which activity to start:

```
// Chooses which activity to start
public class ActivityChooser extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (someCondition)
        {
            // start main application activity
        } else 
        {
            // start activity that plays the video using the native video activity
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

And another activity that starts the native video activity

```
// Starts the native video activity and once it finishes starts the main app activity
public class VideoPlayback extends Activity
{
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (someCondition && !videoIsPlayed)
        {
            videoIsPlayed = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            final Uri data = Uri.parse(videoURL);
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
            startActivity(intent);

            // Question that remains here is how to know when the native video activity is done with
            // the playback in order to start main application activity
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Since there aren't much answers, can one please comment my first approach.

So any suggestions are more than welcome!

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onResume(), your activity is in the running state, and will be in that state until onPause is called. In this state, it's safe to invoke a new activity. Your code in onResume:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
final Uri data = Uri.parse(videoURL);
startActivity(intent);
```

is fine (although obviously you should do something with the uri). This will cause the main activity to pause and start the video activity. Putting that in a different activity is largely unnecessary; however, since you want to know when the video finishes, you could use a VideoView in your VideoPlayback activity, rather than launching it in a new intent. Then you can attach a setOnCompletionListener (MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l) to be informed when the video completes, and return a result to the main intent (which would invoke VideoPlayback using startActivityForResult, and receive its completion notification in onActivityResult.

Comment: Although it seems that my code is valid, it wasn't enough. I still needed to add additional activities; one for choosing and one for a video. Anyway, thank you for the answer!